# Node -- how to determine the location of a file loaded using `require`

Tags: node.js

I understand that `require.resolve("some-module")` will give me the name of the file or directory that's being loaded. But how do I find the *location* of that file. I'm simply trying to read the source code for node's `util` module and want to figure out where it lives.

Comment: Perhaps you can just look at the source in github; https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js.  Also, it's unclear why the full path name returned by `require.resolve()` doesn't tell you where the file is?

Comment: I didn't get a full path from require.resolve(), just the string "util".

Comment: I guess internal modules like `util` don't report the full path with `require.resolve()`.  Not sure why.  Any way, you can find the code in your own filesystem with grep or find it on github.